# programmatically set file visibility on iOS (LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace)

Tags: ios, xamarin, settings

I would like to control at runtime whether or not my app's files should be visible to users in the Files app (based upon some app-internal permissions logic).

As far as I'm aware, this functionality can be set in an app's read-only Info.plist at design-time via the following two keys, and is shipped as part of the app bundle:

- UIFileSharingEnabled
- LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace

I've tried setting these values as false ("YES") in the Info.plist, and then overriding them at runtime with:

```
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetBool(
    true,
    "UIFileSharingEnabled");
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetBool(
    true, 
    "LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace");
```

The values are updated correctly in NSUserDefaults, but it doesn't have any effect on whether or not the app's files are visible in the Files app.

Although I'm on Xamarin I'd still welcome swift/objectiveC answers.

Comment: Info.plist and user defaults are different things.  The info.plist file is "baked in" to the bundle and is read only. You can move your files to the "Application Support" folder if you want them to be backed up but not visible in the files app. See https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/working-with-the-files-app-in-ios-11/

Comment: thanks @Paulw11, I've clarified my question due to your comment.

Comment: User defaults has no effect on file visibility. It is controlled by info.plist only

Comment: any other way I can override the settings in Info.plist at run time?

Comment: No, as I said, that is a read only file because it is in the bundle. The only way to achieve what you want is to move the files out of the documents directory.  If info.plist could be overridden at runtime it would be a bad thing™️

Comment: ok, so there's no inheritance hierarchy of plist files/dictionaries, with a user generated file/dictionary taking precedence. I'll look into moving the files around, but that strikes me as a bit messy really (I also read that prepending with "." would do the same thing) but I'd like to avoid having to search multiple locations. The idea of overriding one or two settings seems much more appealing.

Comment: No, your defaults are your defaults and info.plist is info.plist.   Completely separate